# Encrypting and Decrypting data from App to server, ionic/angular -> java server

Tags: java, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to encrypted data in ionic, send it to server by a POST request and decrypted on server side. And also received encrypted data from server and decrypted on the app.

The one I'm currently testing is [AES256](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes-256), but it seems that the encrypted data is different. Which means that it isn't encrypted or decrypted the correct way once that it gives 2 different values. DO you know some way to make it possible?

```
  encrypt(secureKey, secureIV, data) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      cordova.plugins.AES256.encrypt(secureKey, secureIV, data,
        (encrypedData) => {
          console.log('Encrypted Data----', encrypedData);
          this.decrypt(this.secureKey, this.secureIV, encrypedData);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error----', error);
        });
    });
  }

  decrypt(secureKey, secureIV, encryptedData) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      cordova.plugins.AES256.decrypt(secureKey, secureIV, encryptedData,
        (decryptedData) => {
          console.log('Decrypted Data----', decryptedData);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error----', error);
        });
    });
  }
```

Using this methods on ionic to encrypt and decrypt strings of code. But The value of those on android device is different from the server running on java. How can I make it, to run the same processes for encrypting and decrypting data on the device as on the server?

**UPDATE / SOLVED**
So, I ignore the previous plugin of  `AES 256` of cordova, and install `CryptoJS library`CryptoJS library.
this was the result:

```
    var key = await CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("12345678910123456789012345678901");
var iv = await CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("1234567891123456");
console.log(key + " ; " + iv)
var encrypted = await CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test", key, { iv: iv },
  {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs5
  });
console.log("encrypted -> " + encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64))
```

I had to use `.Latin1.parse` in order to generate the same value in TypeScript/JavaScript as in java. More info, [here](https://www.likeanswer.com/question/479339)